# Updated information using NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification rollback on applying rollback on Context

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, iphonecoredatarecipes

I am using CoreData with multiple contexts (Not Parent-Child). So, I am using  `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` observer to update the information in different contexts. One wired issue I am facing is when a saved data on a background thread is updated on the main thread using `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` then if in future I apply rollback on main thread context then it rolls back the updated info.

Can anyone explain why it is happening?

```
NSMergePolicy *policy = [[NSMergePolicy alloc] initWithMergeType:NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicyType];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {// main thread context
        if (!self.managedObjectContextMainThread) {
            self.managedObjectContextMainThread = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
            [self.managedObjectContextMainThread setMergePolicy:policy];
            [self.managedObjectContextMainThread setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
        }
    }else{
        context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
        [context setMergePolicy:policy];
    }
```

Comment: How do you rollback?

Comment: [Maincontext rollback]; method on main thread context.

Comment: So, then I guess you save the context at some point in between. Can you evaluate that?

Comment: No Actually, I put a general command to rollback any current changes. but it also rollbacks the saved information on another thread context.

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you're asking. How do you setup the contexts? Can you share some code?

Comment: @LukasWürzburger added code.

Comment: Do I understand that right, that you call this code twice? Once from the main thread to initialize `self.managedObjectContextMainThread` and another time from a background thread to initialize `context`?

Comment: Yes your are right :)

Comment: The question here is actually why you want to use two different contexts independent from each other, but manipulating the same data? If you use the parent/child approach you can just rollback changes on the child context and the parent context will not know about it.

Comment: It is an exiting code I cannot make the changes. Main context is not manipulating the same data it just rollbacks the current changes, not the one saved by other thread. Let suppose background thread fetching the person list and save into the db and the new perosn list one from the Local plist file. Now main thread come and it is adding a new person from the application UI meanwhile user press cancel  so now I trigger rollback then it also rollback the new person list from local.

Comment: I guess because you didn't save after reading from the plist file.

Comment: Doing that on the background context.